# Stop Android SyncAdapter sync

Tags: android

I've an app that has multiple accounts and SyncAdapter. I wish to stop Syncing an account as soon as user chooses a different one. I'm doing:

```
ContentResolver.cancelSync(new Account(mAccount, ACCOUNT_TYPE), MyProvider.AUTHORITY);
ContentResolver.removePeriodicSync(new Account(mAccount, ACCOUNT_TYPE), MyProvider.AUTHORITY, new Bundle());
```

And it still syncs. How can I stop it from syncing?

ps i enabled Sync via setSyncAutomatically, requestSync initially.

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason that your original solution didn't work is because you used `setSyncAutomatically`. If however you had enabled sync by using `addPeriodicSync (Account account, String authority, Bundle extras, long pollFrequency)` then your original solution would have worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out.

we've to use:

```
int syncOnOff = 0;

ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, MyProvider.AUTHORITY, syncOnOff);
```

where syncOnOff is 0 for disable, > 0 for enable. |o| why not true false?

Comment: This does not explicitly stops the running sync process, it just says that there will me no further syncing after the actual running sync is finished

Comment: You saved my day!
@Nickolaus: Then you combine it with `ContentResolver.cancelSync(new Account(mAccount, ACCOUNT_TYPE), MyProvider.AUTHORITY);`

Answer (score 10):

the correct answer should be:

use [cancelSync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#cancelSync%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String%29) for cancelling a sync.

explanation according to [this website](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/):

> We have the option to cancel a sync request, by calling cancelSync().
>   If the sync adapter is in “Pending” state, which means it hasn’t
>   started yet, it’ll be canceled immediately and become “Idle”. If it’s
>   already running, the onSyncCanceled() method on the sync adapter will
>   be called. You can use it, for example, to set a “isSyncStopped” flag
>   that the onPerformSync() will check regularly and respond to.